# How can I mock an Observable.throw in an Angular2 test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test the error handling in my Angular2 component and therefore want to mock a service to return an Observable.throw('error'). How can that be done using Jasmine and Karma and Angular 2?

Comment: can you provide us a code example? to add a context to your question an allow us to provide a precise answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should `create` an observable, and just call the observer `error`. For example

```
let mockService = {
  error: false,
  data: 'something',
  getData: () => {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (this.error) {
        observer.error(new Error(..))
      } else {
        observer.next(this.data);
      }
      observer.complete();
    })
  }
}
```

Now for your tests, you can use the mock for both success cases and error cases. For an error case, just set the `error` property to true. In the success case, `next` is called with the data.

When you subscribe to an observable, you can pass three callback, `success`, `error`, and `complete`

```
service.getData().subscribe(
  (data) => {}   // sucess
  (error) => {}  // error
  () => {}       // complete
)
```

So with the `observer`, when calling `observer.next`, `observer.error`, `observer.complete`, the corresponding callback will be called.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with this one. Is it in the test declaration ie "it" that I set the property to "true"? When I set the property to "true" the change is not picked up on in the test declaration I'm setting it in. I could put my code in a plnkr if this would help.

Comment: @bmd Do you find the answer?

Answer (score 38):

Here is my solution for the ones using Rxjs 6

```
let mockService = {
  getData: () => {
    return of({data:'any data'});
  }
}

spyOn(mockService , 'getData').and.callFake(() => {
  return throwError(new Error('Fake error'));
});
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: This can be shorter `let mockService = { getData: of({data:'any data'})};  spyOn(mockService ,  'getData').and.returnValue(throwError(ERROR_RESPONSE))`

Answer (score 13):

You can simply mock `Observable` and throw error object using `Observable.throw({status: 404})` and test error block of observable.

```
const xService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);
const mockCall = spyOn(xService, 'xMethod')
                       .and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 404}));
```

Here I am throwing `http 404` error from `Observable.throw({status: 404})` by mocking `xMethod` of `xSerive` in my test.

Comment: In Rxjs 6+, `Observable.throw` is changed to the static operator `throwError`.

Comment: In `RxJs 6+` you don't have to import the whole observable, you just do with `throw()`

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version for RxJS 6:

```
let mockService = {
  getData: () => {
    return of({data:'any data'});
  }
}

spyOn(mockService , 'getData').and.returnValue(throwError('test error'));
```