# Mocking an HTTP error Observable in Jasmine and RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs, jasmine, http-status-codes, rxjs-observables

This question is sort of a duplicate, but since I can't comment on other questions I've had to open a new one.

I'm running into a bug in a jasmine test where a function is supposed to handle an error from a service call. The service call in question returns an RxJS `Observable` of an `HttpResponse`. The function being tested seems to not receive anything from the service, even when using a spy to throw the error. The code follows this structure:

**component.ts:**

```
public thingThatCallsService() {
    this.foo = false;
    this.service.bar()
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {log(res)},
            (err) => {
                log(err) // Logs empty string during test
                if (err.status === 400) this.foo = true;
            }
        );
}
```

**mockService.ts:** (The test suite is set to use this instead of the actual service)

```
public bar() {
    return of(new HttpResponse());
}
```

**test.ts:**

```
it("sets foo to true if bar returns an error", fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(service, "bar").and.returnValue(
        throwError(() => new HttpErrorResponse({status: 400}))
    );
    component.thingThatCallsService();
    tick();
    componentFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(service.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.foo).toBeTrue(); // Keeps failing
}))
```

Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969759/how-can-i-mock-an-observable-throw-in-an-angular2-test) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960146/testing-error-case-with-observables-in-services) either have answers where a string should be returned, not an object with a `status` field; or answers that contain outdated/invalid code (for instance, `new Error({status: 404})` is not a valid instantiation of an `Error`).

It should also be noted that the code works correctly outside of the test; i.e. when the service call encounters an error with a specific status code, `foo` is set to true.

Any advice on how to have the `Observable` properly throw an error for the subscription to handle would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following to see if it works?

```
spyOn(service, "bar").and.returnValue(
        throwError(() => ({ status: 400 }))
    );
```

Also see what the log outputs in this scenario as well. I am not sure why `HttpErrorResponse` does not work, it should work.